# hrefs are not clickable

Tags: html, css

My a href tags are not clickable on my website, i heared its because i have a z-index, but i can't remove the z-index tag because its crucial on my website. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="NewsPosts">    
        <p><h5>Posted by Sir Biscuit on November 28, 2014</h5><a href="../assets/posts/1.html">Website Developed by Sir Biscuit</a></p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#NewsPosts {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
top: -80px;
font-family: "arial";
font-size: 18px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #888888;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1
}
```

Comment: why do you set z-index: -1 ??? Set it to 1 and works fine.

Comment: You would pretty much have to remove the z-index on that. Basically, it's setting your anchors behind the body element, which contains everything.

Comment: *"i can't remove the z-index tag because its crucial on my website"* -Isn't going to help with arriving at a solution. You'll have to explain why it is crucial so that one can suggest what else can be done to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a negative z-index on that tag, set a higher z-index on the elements that needs to be in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing z-index of a

```
#NewsPosts a{
z-index:999;
}
```